# Translation Golf XXIII - Yoda's Epitaph

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

> This game has finished. [The winner is VeAqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22961/12637).

---

Welcome to a new edition of the game!
If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

---

This edition's proposed text is an excerpt from Star Wars Episode VI - The Return of the Jedi. Ladies and gentlemen, I give you Yoda's last lines:

> Remember, a Jedi's strength flows from the Force. But beware. Anger, fear, aggression. The dark side are they. Once you start down the dark path, forever will it dominate your destiny. Luke... Luke... do not... do not underestimate the powers of the Emperor or suffer your father's fate you will. Luke, when gone am I... the last of the Jedi will you be. Luke, the Force runs strong in your family. Pass on what you have learned, Luke. There is... another... Sky... walker.
>
> <sub>(351 characters)</sub>

Example, non-golfed, translation:

> Recuerda, el poder de un Jedi de la Fuerza proviene. Pero cuidado. Ira, miedo, agresión, el reverso tenebroso son. Si a recorrer el camino tenebroso comienzas, para siempre tu destino dominará. Luke... Luke... no... no subestimes los poderes del Emperador, o el destino de tu padre sufrirás. Luke, cuando ido me haya... el último de los Jedi serás. Luke, la Fuerza poderosa en tu familia es. Enseña lo que has aprendido, Luke. Hay... otro... Sky... walker.
>  
>  <sub>(342 characters)</sub>

---

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters? Join us in [Translation-Golf!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66153/translation-golf), our game-specific chat room, or in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### <strike>171</strike> 162 caracteres

> Ve, el poder Jedi es fuerza. Ojo: ira, temor, bonche. Lado opaco va ahí. Tomalo y tu hado es... Ignorá poder real, hado paterno pená. Al irme... Jedi final sos. Gran poder tu casa trae, Luke. Da tu saber... Más Sky... walker... hay

Esta traducción solo puede un Jedi defender (que me gano el odio de todos los fans de Star Wars...)

- Supongamos que Yoda vino a Colombia, a tierras occidentales (Costa pacífica, Tierra Paisa, Pastusa o Valluna) para que pueda vosear.
- Casi todo el discurso lo pongo en imperativo
- Ve: Imperativo de ver en su [segunda acepción](http://dle.rae.es/?id=baOo6Gz%7CbaR8qnC)
- Ojo: Acepción 21
- [Bonche](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=bonche) (gracias por la Asale): II. 1. Disputa, pelea
- Opaco por dark
- Hado como destino
- Real con su segundo término, primera acepción
- Ignorá traduce underestimate
- Pená por "suffer ... you wil"
- Irme por morir (Acepción 31)
- Casa por familia (Acepción 5)
- Dejo una sola vez a Luke mencionado

Cuyas ideas tomé, sin intención lo hice, empiezo números mirando y a mermar juego...

Comment: Tu uso del voseo grandioso es. Tu traducción encantado me ha.

Comment: Has sido declarado ganador, tienes 48 horas para publicar una nueva edición del TG.

Answer (score 5):

## 178 caracteres

> Mira, la Garra, fuerte en los tuyos, es el poder del Jedi. Vigila! Ira, miedo, daño son la Mala Vía sin retorno. Valora el poder del Zar o te verás como tu papi, Luke. Al irme serás el último Jedi. Educa con tu saber. Hay... otro... Skywalker.

- Traduzco Dark Side (Reverso Tenebroso u Oscuro) como la Mala Vía (el Mal Camino)
- El Emperador ahora es el [Zar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cNf58Lf) (soberano de ciertos países del este)
- <strike>La Fuerza es [el Qí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%C3%AC):  En la cultura tradicional china, literalmente «aire, aliento, disposición de ánimo», es el principio activo que forma parte de todo ser vivo y que se podría traducir como "flujo vital de energía". Al igual que "la Fuerza" es aquello que nos conecta y de lo que el universo está formado.</strike>
- Uso "fuerte en los tuyos" para "fuerte/intenso en tu familia".
- Uso "[garra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IvZfWwx)" en su tercera acepción (Fuerza, empuje.) para designar a la Fuerza

Comment: Algunos comentarios: dices que has traducido "Dark Side" por "Mala Vía" pero has acabado usando "Mal Camino". Y por otro lado te has comido todos los "Luke", no has dejado ni uno en el texto, deberías explicar el motivo, ya que tenemos que saber a quién se dirige Yoda.

Comment: Me encanta tu adaptación de la Fuerza como el "Qì", pero lamentablemente no encuentro esa palabra en el diccionario. ¿Puedes defender su uso como neologismo citando textos de prensa, novelas, libros, manuales u otros que la usen?

Answer (score 4):

#### <s>190</s> 163

> Fuerza, del Jedi poder es. Tu rama mucha ha. Ojo: ira, miedo, ataque. Lado negro son. Síguelo y regirá tu hado. Luke... valora al Rey... o como papá sufrirás. Sin mí... el Jedi final serás. Da lo que sabes. Hay... otro... Sky... walker.

Comment: No suelo pasarme por el Translation Golf y seguro que no conozco muy bien las reglas pero me parece que "Emperador" es ineludible. ¿Rey? _not so much_

Comment: Jajaja...¡Ah! Le estas dando de su misma medicina. Excelente.

Comment: Esto es un juego, y la verdad es que entra dentro de lo que solemos hacer, pero yo también pensaba que "emperador" era ineludible. Como "norma de la casa" estaría feo que yo copiase "Rey" en mi propuesta, ya que la ha usado otro, pero si uso "duque" o "conde" (5 letras en vez de las 3 de Rey, pero menos que Emperador) es válido? Y "zar"? Yo la usaría, pero creo que desvirtúa un poco. @charlie, puedo usar "zar" para referirme al Emperador?

Comment: @Diego ningún problema con "zar", "rey", "césar" ni palabras similares que se usen para gobernantes.

Comment: ¡Excelente reducción! ¿Qué significa "Tu rama mucha ha"?

Answer (score 4):

### <strike>186</strike> <strike>179</strike> 174

> El vigor Jedi nace del Brío, recio en tu sangre. ¡eh! ¿ira, miedo, atraco? : ¡negrura que dominaría tu destino! subestimar al sultán es sufrir como tu padre. Yendome serás el último Jedi. Pasa lo sabido, Luke. Hay otro Skywalker

- Usé [sultán](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=YghqW6w) en lugar de Emperador
- *dark path* la traduje como negrura
- [*recia*](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=VRTZAej%7CVRUXi5l) la uso como sinónimo de fuerte
- Uso [atraco](http://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/agresi%C3%B3n) en lugar de agresión
- [brío](http://dle.rae.es/?id=672nRvF) como sinónimo de fuerza.
- [*eh*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ERYOg9R) para llamar la atención (beware)